# Could open-telemetry collector be used without instrumentation?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, open-telemetry, argo

We are building application with argo workflows. We are wondering if we could just set up opentelemetry collector inside of our kubernetes cluster, and start using it as stdout exporter into elastic stack. Couldn't find information if OTEL can export logs without instrumentation. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes. For logs you don't need instrumentation, in principle.

However, logs are still in development (so, you'd need to track upstream and deal with the fact that you're operating against a moving target. There are a number of components upstream you can use, for example, you can use the [Filelog Receiver](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/filelogreceiver) and the [Elasticsearch Exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/elasticsearchexporter) in a pipeline. I recently did a [POC and demo](https://gist.github.com/mhausenblas/98dd345cf5476c0b025c724ea73df1a8) (just ignore the custom collector part and use upstream) that you could use as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the following OpenTelemetry (Otel) website:

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/data-collection/

the Receiver component of Otel Collector can be either push or pull based. For example, using the following Java agent of Otel Collector:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation

a Spring Boot jar can be bootstrapped with such an agent without the need to change any code inside this Spring Boot app and still be able to push the telemetry data onto the Otel Collector. Another example is to use a puller instance of Otel Collector to pull the telemetry data out of a Redis runtime using the following example:

https://signoz.io/blog/redis-opentelemetry/